How to open file paths in vim using [[hints.enabled]] Alacritty
I am using Alacritty terminal for quite some time and it has a great feature to follow hyperlinks when clicking Ctrl+Shift+U. I am using MAC so a default program is open.
Iam trying to add one more section
[[hints.enabled]]
command = "vim" # On Linux/BSD
# command = "open" # On macOS
# command = { program = "cmd", args = [ "/c", "start", "" ] } # On Windows
hyperlinks = false
post_processing = true
persist = false
mouse.enabled = true
binding = { key = "F", mods = "Control|Shift" }
regex = '(\n|.)*/\.[^/]*[^~]'

The goal would be pretty straightforward. If Alacritty finds on a current focused terminal
paths like lines below, I would like to follow them with vim.
~/path/to/file.(whatever suffix)
../path/to/file.(whatever suffix)
path/to/file.(whatever suffix)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .terraform.lock.hcl
        modified:   main.tf
...
etc
...

Any ideas ?
The problem is that even if I see in logs
[DEBUG] [alacritty] Launched vim with args ["~/path/to/some/file.yaml"]
nothing really happens. File is not getting opened in Alacritty with Vim.
Thx

Is that supposed to obey $PATH?  Does the behavior change if you provide an explicit path to the vim binary?

open uses the default application for the specific file type. I doubt that this will is Alacritty/vim. But could you try with a path for a html file (create one if necessary) to see if it works in that case (should open the file in your default browser)?

Also, your first code snippet has the macOS part commented out. Can you please replace the snipped with the code you are actually using?

Hi @nohillside, yes it works with "open" keyword, but my specific use case is to stay in Alacritty terminal. The whole idea is that you work in a terminal and once Ctrl+Shift+F was pressed I would like to have an option to immediately open it within same terminal (Alacritty) using vim.  The same thing works out of the box for URLS in Alacritty.
"open" opens VSC which I am not using.

@MarcWilson yes I have also tried to provide full path, but with no success.

The challenge here is that you want to open vim running in Alacritty, but macOS can only associate one application with a file type and this application is expected to open the file then. Does Alacritty even accept files to be opened as parameter? Can this be configured within Alacritty, so it then opens vim?

But maybe open is the wrong path for this. What happens if you set the command for the hint to be vim?

@nohillside well regex matched and logs show
[58.743371041s] [DEBUG] [alacritty] Launched vim with args [".config/alacritty/alacritty.toml"]  but in reality, nothing gets open nowhere. In this particular case, I had on my screen file path .config/alacritty/alacritty.toml, so this works nice. The problem is the way how MAC is handling this opening in VIM. I thought that this will be not an issue.

Please add the specific config you used, the text you clicked on and the result you got to the question. Currently there are too many unclarities to really analyze what is wrong.

Sure, here is my config: https://github.com/xjantoth/dotfiles/blob/main/.config/alacritty/alacritty.toml#L38-L47
I am attaching image https://github.com/xjantoth/dotfiles/blob/main/alac.png where I clicked at 3 files. YOu can see respective logs
[49.055209375s] [DEBUG] [alacritty] Launched vim with args [".config/alacritty/alacritty.toml"] [53.693062208s] [DEBUG] [alacritty] Launched vim with args [".tmux.conf"] [55.622724500s] [DEBUG] [alacritty] Launched vim with args [".zshrc"]

Does it work if the path you click on is absolute (starts with /)?

I mean in only works with VSCODE,, but not with VIM in a Alacritty and that is my concern from the begining.

Is this facility supposed to be able to launch terminal applications in the current window?  It doesn't sound like it is.
